# How to enable multiple views at once using dojox/app?

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile, dojox.app

I am building a web application using dojox/app, and my config.json file is the following:

```
{
"id": "app",
"name": "app",
"description": "My app",
"dependencies": [
    "commonapp/app",
    "commonapp/BaseViewController",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojox/app/utils/mvcModel",
    "dojox/mvc/EditStoreRefListController",
    "dojo/store/Observable"
],
"controllers": [
"dojox/app/controllers/Load",
"dojox/app/controllers/Transition",
"dojox/app/controllers/Layout",
"dojox/app/controllers/HistoryHash"],

"stores": {

},
"models": {

},

"defaultView": "MainTemplate",
"views": {
    "MainTemplate": {
        "template": "commonapp/templates/MainTemplate.html",
        "controller": "commonapp/templates/MainTemplate.js",
        "nls": "commonapp/templates/nls/MainTemplate",
        "defaultView": "LoginView",
        "views": {
            "LoginView": {
                "template": "commonapp/login/LoginView.html",
                "controller": "commonapp/login/LoginView.js",
                "nls": "commonapp/login/nls/LoginView"
            },
            "AppView": {
                "template": "commonapp/app/AppView.html",
                "controller": "commonapp/app/AppView.js",
                "nls": "commonapp/app/nls/AppView",
                "views": {
                    "LeftContainerView": {
                        "template": "commonapp/app/leftContainer/LeftContainerView.html",
                        "controller": "commonapp/app/leftContainer/LeftContainerView.js",
                        "nls": "commonapp/app/leftContainer/nls/LeftContainerView"
                    },
                    "RightContainerView": {
                        "template": "commonapp/app/rightContainer/RightContainerView.html",
                        "controller": "commonapp/app/rightContainer/RightContainerView.js",
                        "nls": "commonapp/app/rightContainer/nls/RightContainerView"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Everything works fine until I added the LeftContainerView and RightContainerView. In this particular case, I want both views to be active at the same time. The problem is, if I set a default view for either LeftContainerView or RightContainerView, one the default one appears. But, if I programatically trigger events to show both views when the AppView is loaded, one of them will be automatically hidden, and the problem stays.

Basically, the idea is that AppView will have a fixedsplitter, and on each of the panes, I want to place one of the child views. Does anyone have an idea of how can I get both LeftContainerView and RightContainerView active at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this way:

```
"defaultView": "LeftContainerView+RightContainerView"
```

as indicated in https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/app.html#defaultview ?

(Would also be useful to tell the Dojo version you are using.)

Comment: Hi, the Dojo version is the 1.9, so the information on that page applies. However, using multiple defaultViews only seems to work at the application level, and not on the view level. If I use your suggestion, neither LeftContainerView not RightContainerView load. I have also tried using the full qualified name (MainTemplate,AppView,LeftContainerView+MainTemplate,AppView,RightContainerView), but with the same result. After, I have tried publishing the transitionEvent using both views with the qualified name. In this case, both views are fired, but one of them is deactivated immediately

Comment: I'm not a dojox/app specialist, so I may miss something, but I do see it working with two default views here: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.3/dojo-release-1.9.3/dojox/app/tests/layoutApp2/index.html (also works in 1.9.0). 

The configuration of the default views is here: https://github.com/dmachi/dojox_application/blob/dojo19/tests/layoutApp2/config.json#L86

Comment: That sample seems to be what i'm looking for. I think the issue might be about the constraint areas of the app. Setting them to left or center seems to solve the problem. I'll download that source code, and adapt the config.json to my case. Thank you!